# echo "#!" fails -- "event not found"

Tags: bash, echo

The following fails and I don't understand why:

```
$ echo "#!"
```

the following also fails with the same error message:

```
$ echo "\#!"
```

the error message:

```
-bash: !": event not found
```

Why does it fail? How should the `echo` be done instead?

Comment: [rici's answer to a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25021905/874188) is really stellar if you want a detailed, long exposition.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with that code in Bash 5.0. Maybe it's been patched. But I can reproduce it with similar commands, like `echo "#!foobar"`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `!` character is used for `csh`-style history expansion.

If you do not use this feature, `set +o histexpand` (aka `set +H`) turns off this behavior.  It is turned off for scripts, but often enabled for interactive use.  In such cases, my personal recommendation is to turn it off permanently by adding `set +o histexpand` to your `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc` if you don't have a `.bash_profile`; this is more complex than I want to try to fit into a parenthetical).

As a workaround, if for some reason you cannot or don't want to turn off and forget about this legacy `csh` feature, you can use single quotes instead of double quotes -- keeping in mind, of course, their different semantics.  If you need to combine quoting with variable interpolation, for example, you can change

```
echo "#!$SHELL"  # oops, history expansion breaks this
```

into

```
 echo '#!'"$SHELL"
```

(notice the adjacent single-quoted and double-quoted strings; after the shell is done with this, the quotes will be removed and the string `#!` will be output next to the value of the variable `SHELL` with no space between them) or a number of other common workarounds like

```
 printf '#!%s\n' "$SHELL"
```

... though as remarked in a comment, even [single quotes don't necessarily prevent this from happening when they are at the end of a pipeline.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917491/785213)

Comment: Rolled back the edit with @GaborJozan's answer as that was [posted separately](/a/37741294/874188) anyway, but has the obvious flaw that it adds a space where none was present before.

Comment: You can use single instead of double quotes _except_ in some odd circumstances, such as where the single quotes are in the downstream part of a pipeline, as noted in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37917491/785213). Yes, this can be exasperating sometimes; you could momentarily `set +o histexpand` if you can't work around it another way.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I added a section emphasizing that there are obviously differences between single and double quotes and included a couple of workarounds.

Comment: ... or even: `echo -e "#\041$SHELL"`

Comment: Best answer on [`[bash] "event not found"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+%22event+not+found%22) unfortunely not at 1st place

Comment: @F.Hauri Depends on how you sort the search results, but the top result by relevance wasn't so great; I have now marked it as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 9):

```
echo '#!'
```

Basically, with double quotes (`"`) aka "weak quoting", Bash does some wacky things with the string, like variable substitution. With single (`'`) aka "strong quoting" the string is taken literally.

See e.g. [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting) for a more in-depth explanation of quoting.

Answer (score 9):

By default, bash supports `csh` compatible history-expansion.

In bash

```
echo #!
```

will only print a newline, as `#` starts a comment.

In

```
echo "#!"
```

the `#` is part of the string started with `"`.  Such strings are still inspected by bash for special characters.  `!` is a special character iff it is followed by any other text.

```
-bash: !": event not found
```

In this case, bash expects the `!"` token to refer to a previous command in shell history starting with `"`, and does not find one.  All by itself, `!` will not trigger this behaviour:

```
$ echo \# !
# !

$ echo fee ! fie
fee ! fie
```

Finally,

```
$ echo !echo
```

produces two lines, the first line is printed by the shell to show how the pattern above expands to:

```
echo echo '# !'
```

while the second line is just the result of executing the expanded command:
    echo # !

---

See Also: The [Bash man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) on [History Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction)

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround may be to put an extra space after the "!" :

```
# echo "#! "
#!
```

Comment: For years this is how I've worked around the error message (which I never _really_ understood until today) for one-liners like `grep -q pattern somefile.txt && echo "YAY! "`. And probably still will, because double-quoting strings in the shell is just in my muscle memory.

Answer (score 2):

In my case all commands are working. Maybe you can specify your environment.

```
$ echo "\#\!"
\#\!
$ echo "#!"
echo "#"
#
$ echo "#!"
echo "#"
#
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.48(1)-release
```

Comment: Clearly then you have already disabled `histexpand`