# Curl with exclamation mark + hasthag in target URL

Tags: php, curl, ssh, nginx

I'm trying todo a simple curl with a hashtag in target url - but getting errors.

I know this script works, i've used it many times before.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$curl = curl_init('http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/d3YvU8/http://www.nginx-hosting.co.uk');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
$result = curl_exec($curl);

if ($result == ("")) {
echo ("Nothing to curl");
}
else {
echo $result;
}

?>
```

Here is the above script in action: http://www.nginx-hosting.co.uk/curl_test.php

As you can see the ouput is nothing like it's supposed to be. I ran the same command through SSH :

```
curl http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/d3YvU8/http://www.nginx-hosting.co.uk
```

But get this error message -bash: !/d3YvU8/http: event not found

I assume this is because the target url has an exclamation mark in it or a hashtag.

Could someone point me in the right direction please. Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI `#!` is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [echo "#!" fails -- "event not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816122/echo-fails-event-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried your script it works just fine, about `-bash: !/d3YvU8/http: event not found` error you should use quotes like: curl '
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/d3YvU8/http://www.nginx-hosting.co.uk'

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but I tried double quotes and got the same problem. Didnt even think of single quotes.

The curled result is not as expected, its not the same output as visiting the url directly.

Comment: Because it's javascript who handles everything after shebang, you need something like http://phantomjs.org/ to open url with js support.

Comment: I have just been reading a similar post which the answer was phantonjs.org I will check this out.

Comment: Right then, just installed phantomjs and now getting this problem. Works fine from SSH but doesnt work from PHP. Should I open a new question to resolve and reference this one?

Comment: What do you mean does not work from php? How are you using with php?