# How can I use !! as part of my .inputrc keyboard binding?

Tags: bash, readline

In Bash, I'd like to create a binding in my `.inputrc` that makes use of the `!!` built-in to repeat the last command.  But this doesn’t seem to properly expand the `!!`

```
bind -x '"\C-t": echo $(!!)'
```

When I invoke the above binding (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) I just get this:

```
-bash: !!: command not found
```

Likewise the simpler

```
 bind -x '"\C-t": echo !!'
```

Just yields

```
!!
```

Instead of the actual command.
Obviously my real use-case is more substantive than this example, this is just an illustration of the problem.

**Edit:**

This question has nothing to do with [echo "#!" fails -- "event not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816122/echo-fails-why) which it is claimed mine is a duplicate of.  That question pertains to a generalized failure of `!*` expansion in regular bash due to quoting issues or lack of history.  My question on the other hand is very specific to the context of being used inside an `.inputrc` file (or perhaps an alias), where a different set of factors come into play.  On my regular command line, the so-called "bang expansions" have always worked fine.  It's only in these special contexts where the problems arose, and hence led to this question.

Comment: I think it is possible that under the `bind` command  `!!` is not considered as a command. Your last example is so obvious, it is considered as a literal letter.

Comment: Maybe you can done it by something like this `eval $(tail -2 ~/.bash_history | head -1)` instead of `echo !!`. I'm not sure but please try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems there's something odd going on with shell quoting.

This does not work

```
bind -x '"\C-l": "!! \n"'
```

But putting this in .inputrc does

```
"\C-l": "!! \n"
```

Don't really understand why the former doesn't work, but at least the latter does.

EDIT: OK got it.  Apparently the "-x" isn't needed when defining on the cmd line.  So we can simply write

```
bind '"\C-l": "!! \n"'
```

Using -x tells bind not to interfere with what you've already typed (almost like a primal ncurses approximation of a modal window!) which is not what I'm after.  Thanks to the accepted answer on [In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command) for this insight!

Answer (score 0):

```
"\C-t": "fc -s\n"
```

`fc -s` re-executes the last command, and `fc` is also a builtin:

```
$ type fc
fc is a shell builtin
```