# Setting Environment Variable ends with "-bash: !": event not found"

Tags: firebase, gmail, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I am setting up a typical email function for firebase to alert me when a new record is added.  In my terminal, I am inputting the following:

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="MyEmail@gmail.com" gmail.password="MyPassword1!"
```

This returns the error:  -bash: !": event not found

I CAN set just the email if i want and it works fine, but setting the password gets me this issue.  So, this works:

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="MyEmail@gmail.com"
```

This does not:

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="MyEmail@gmail.com" gmail.password="MyPassword1!"
```

or

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.password="MyPassword1!"
```

Thoughts??

I would expect this to work and in fact i previously had it working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [echo "#!" fails -- "event not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816122/echo-fails-event-not-found)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got an error message because `!` character in your password is expanded by `bash` (you are using double quotes). Try simple quotes instead :

```
firebase functions:config:set \
    gmail.email="MyEmail@gmail.com" \
    gmail.password='MyPassword1!'
```

See also [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark) for reference.