# Bash event not found

Tags: linux, bash

I was running curl in my linux terminal:

`curl -u ‘user’:’$3cur!’ -T udhaya.war ‘http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/manager/text/deploy?path=/udhaya`

I get the following error:

`bash: !’: event not found`

Comment: This is not a programming question (you just don't know bash interactive use) and as such off-topic here.  You may try [unix.se] or [su], but make sure you a) read their rules and b) make sure you did **some** research before posting.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816122/echo-fails-event-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is with the "!" mark in your  ‘user’:’$3cur!’.

See following example :

```
[root@mymachine~]# echo "!"
-bash: !: event not found
```

We need to turnoff history expansion to avoid it using 'set +H' before running your curl command as shown below:

```
[root@mymachine ~]# set +H
[root@mymachine ~]# echo "!"
!
```

Comment: Not only are you answering off-topic questions, your suggestion may work, but it's tipping out the baby with the bath water ... a simple replacement of `"` with `'` would have done.