# Executing dynamic bash script including function declarations in one line with Go

Tags: bash, shell, go, command-line-interface

I am writing a bash task runner in Go which has a simple concept:

1. it reads a `Taskfile` , which is a a bash script containing task definitions (simple bash function declarations)
2. it adds dynamically additional stuff
3. Executes a command based on passed arguments

Here is a simplified example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    //simplified for a dynamically built script
    taskFileContent := "#!/bin/bash\n\ntask:foo (){\n  echo \"test\"\n}\n"
    // simplified for passed arguments
    task := "\ntask:foo"
    bash, _ := exec.LookPath("bash")
    cmd := exec.Command(bash, "-c", "\"$(cat << EOF\n"+taskFileContent+task+"\nEOF\n)\"")
    fmt.Println(cmd.String())
    out, _ := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

My problem now is, that this does not work if it gets executed via Go and I get this error

```
task:foo: No such file or directory
```

But it does work if I just execute the generated script directly in the shell like this:

```
$ /opt/opt/homebrew/bin/bash -c "$(cat << EOF
#!/bin/bash

task:foo (){
  echo "test"
}

task:foo
EOF
)"

test   <-- printed out from the `task:foo` above
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: I'm not expert on bash, but in my experience it's tricky to expect full shell functionality from cli invokations like `exec.Command`. Often, the feature set is limited - check the [this](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#pkg-overview) part of the according Go documentation. My guess is that the `cat <<` won't work.

Comment: What value do you get from doing this over putting the text of your function in an environment variable and `eval`ing that variable? It looks like a lot of extra overhead (heredocs are implemented by creating temporary files, so even some I/O overhead!) for no obvious benefit.

Comment: Also, note that `task:foo` is not, as a function name, accepted by all versions of bash out there. Some old releases only allow non-POSIX-compliant names when the (legacy ksh / non-POSIX) `function` keyword is use; newer releases are more lenient, but sticking to standard-compliant names is the better practice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I will try that and come back 

Comment: @NotX, one needs to explicitly invoke a shell to get full shell functionality, but that's exactly what `bash` `-c` _does_. (The `system()` equivalents in other languages discussed by the docs you link use `sh` `-c`, but `bash` `-c` as an alternative offers extensions to the language that `/bin/sh` isn't guaranteed to have).

Comment: That said -- stepping back and taking a closer look, I'm in a place to write up an answer describing what went wrong here.

Comment: (there's not much value to `eval` either, except maybe to move content off the command line -- which is more often world-readable by all users on the system -- to the environment, which on operating systems following recent best practices is readable only by the same account or by root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First: There's no point to a heredoc here.

You're getting nothing that you wouldn't have from:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command(bash, "-c", taskFileContent+"\n"+task)
```

Your code is simpler if you leave it out.

---

#### Second: An explanation of *why*

When, at a shell, you run:

```bash
/opt/opt/homebrew/bin/bash -c "$(cat << EOF
#!/bin/bash

task:foo (){
  echo "test"
}

task:foo
EOF
)"
```

...the `"`s surrounding the `$()` are syntax not to the copy of bash that's *being started*, but to the copy of bash that's *parsing your command*. They tell that copy of bash that the results of the command substitution are to be passed as exactly one string, not subject to string-splitting or globbing.

Similarly, the `$(cat <<EOF`, the `EOF`, and the final `)"` are *likewise* instructions to your interactive shell, not the noninteractive shell it invokes. It's the interactive shell that runs `cat` (with a temporary file containing the heredoc's content connected to its stdin), reading the stdout of that copy of `cat`, and then substituting that data into a single argument that it passes to `bash -c`.

In your Go program, you have no interactive shell, so you should be using Go syntax -- not shell syntax -- for all these steps. And insofar as those steps are things there's no reason to do in Go to the first place (no point to writing your data file to a temporary file, no point to having `/bin/cat` read that file's contents, no point to having a subprocess running a command substitution to generate a string -- consisting of those contents -- to put on the command line of your final shell), it's much more sensible to just leave all those steps out.

Comment: I just prepared an answer with a simple example using the from you mentioned env var approach, which also worked, but this here is the real solution. simpler than before and just working. the a lot for the fast help!

Comment: BTW, if you do end up using the eval form, make sure you're running `eval "$var"`, not `eval $var`. The bugs caused by leaving out the quotes are subtle, but that doesn't mean they can't sting.

Answer (score 0):

test with printf gave me the reason

```
pintf "#!/bin/bash\n\ntask:foo (){\n  echo \"test\"\n}\n"
-bash: !/bin/bash\n\ntask: event not found
```

this behaviour is explained here [echo "#!" fails -- "event not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816122/echo-fails-event-not-found)

The ! character is used for csh-style history expansion. You need to turn off this behaviour...

so you should add `set +o histexpand` to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: It's already turned off by default in noninteractive shells, though; if an interactive shell is being used to run a script, something is very wrong.

Comment: Which is to say: This error message is created when you test the code in an interactive shell, but the OP's Go program creates a noninteractive shell, so it can't hit this bug.

Comment: @Charles i did not know that, thanks for clarrclarification