# Create a shell script with a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, heredoc

I'm creating a script which create file and insert content using

```
cat > /etc/file <<END
FILE CONTENT
END
```

It works for most files but it doesn't work when file content have shell commands in it.
I tried with the echo command but i have the same problem.

Why does it execute commands ?

Comment: Please paste the command that is not working to you

Comment: If the here-doc contains `$variable`, the variables will be expanded. You need to use `<<'END'` to prevent variables from being expanded.

Comment: Correct ! I had to use backtick escapes to solve my problem, my script contains variables wich were executed. How does i set your answer as valid? Thanks by the way

Comment: @Barmar maybe you can post this as an answer, as you solved it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash tips needed for understanding how to escape characters in command-line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659777/bash-tips-needed-for-understanding-how-to-escape-characters-in-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

The file's content includes `$variables` wich are expanded. To avoid variable expansion, I had to use single-quote escapes `'END'`.